# Electron.JS + devtoolsinstaller: 'BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension' is deprecated and will be removed. Please use 'session.loadExtension' instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, google-chrome-devtools

After updating my Electron app from Electron 8.2.5 to 9.0.0, the following errors start to appear in the terminal:

```
[1] (electron) 'BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension' is deprecated and will be removed. Please use 'session.loadExtension' instead.
[1] Added Extension:  [object Object]
[1] (electron) 'BrowserWindow.getDevToolsExtensions' is deprecated and will be removed. Please use 'session.getAllExtensions' instead.
[1] Added Extension:  [object Object]
```

My electron app uses [`electron-devtools-installer`](https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer) to install React Developer Tools and Redux DevTools after the Electron app has loaded.

How can we make use of `session.loadExtension` and `session.getAllExtensions` to install devtools properly in Electron 9?

---

```
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;
const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");
let mainWindow;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const installExtensions = async () => {
  const { default: installExtension, REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS, REDUX_DEVTOOLS } = require('electron-devtools-installer');

  const extensions = [REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS, REDUX_DEVTOOLS];
  for (const extension of extensions) {
    try {
      const name = await installExtension(extension);
      console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('An error occurred: ', err);
    }
  }
}

...

app.on("ready", async () => {
  createWindow();

  if (isDev) {
    await installExtensions();
    mainWindow.webContents.on("did-frame-finish-load", () => {
      mainWindow.webContents.once("devtools-opened", () => {
        mainWindow.focus();
      });
      mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools({
        mode: 'undocked'
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Regarding the log error:

```
[1] Added Extension:  [object Object]
```

I ran into the same problem. `installExtension` actually returns the extension object and you can get the extension name with:

```js
const installedExt = await installExtension(extension);
console.log(`Added Extension:  ${installedExt.name}`);
```

Regarding the deprecation warning:

```
[1] (electron) 'BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension' is deprecated and will be removed. Please use 'session.loadExtension' instead.
```

The package [electron-devtools-installer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-devtools-installer) should be updated to support the new way of registering the devtools as explained in: [Electron API docs for devtools extension](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/extensions.md)

Example:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, session } = require('electron')
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({...})

const ext = await session.defaultSession.loadExtension('/path/to/unpacked/chrome-ext')
```

I will try to make a PR for this package to fix the deprecation warning.

Please let me know if this helps.